# Can the 20.04 dock hide apps not on the current worksapce?

Tags: 20.04, workspaces, ubuntu-dock

I have just done a clean install of 20.04. I make heavy use of workspaces, but the behavior of the dock in relation to workspaces has changed, and I'd like the old behavior back.

How I'd like it to work: When on a workspace, the dock only shows app icons for apps with windows in that workspace. If I click on an app icon, it only offers me windows that are in that workspace.

How it works now: The dock shows me all apps and all windows for that app. So if I have 2 Firefox windows in each of 4 workspaces (and I often have more), then when I click on Firefox I have to look through 8 windows to find the one I want, not just 2.

How close can I get to my desired experience with 20.04?